# Move mouse pointer in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to move the mouse so that it is positioned inside a text input using JavaScript?

Comment: You cannot move the actual mouse pointer in Javascript.

Comment: You can, however move a pointer shaped image and pretend that you can. :-)

Comment: Better yet, you can move a cat image around, following the mouse cursor, and try to use it to chase the cursor into the position you want.

Comment: It's be a nightmare if mouse pointer or cursor can be moved. Havoc will break loose!

Comment: Just make the textbox big enough and never worry anymore. The mouse will always be inside of it.

Comment: This browser experiment does seems to move cursor https://javier.xyz/control-user-cursor/

Comment: Are you guys sure about that. What about dispatching your own mouse events? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent

Comment: If you cannot control the mouse, perhaps you can control the page. JavaScript offers facilities to *read* the mouse position, and to *scroll* the page. So it is possible to add some whitespace on top and below, and scroll the entire thing to hit the mouse.

Answer (score 30):

I don't know about moving the actual rendered mouse pointer, but could you just set the focus on the element?

```js
document.getElementById('the_text_input_id').focus()
```

Comment: impossible to move the mouse, confirmed.

Answer (score 7):

Please see this question:

> [Mouse move on element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105733/mouse-move-on-element/2105766)

Besides that, I think you are committing major design mistake by taking control of any of the users input in any way (maybe besides setting the focus of a form element)

Answer (score 7):

Here is a function that select text in an `input` or `textarea`:

```js
function textSelect(inp, s, e) {
    e = e || s;
    if (inp.createTextRange) {
        var r = inp.createTextRange();
        r.collapse(true);
        r.moveEnd('character', e);
        r.moveStart('character', s);
        r.select();
    } else if (inp.setSelectionRange) {
        inp.focus();
        inp.setSelectionRange(s, e);
    }
}
```

To place the cursor at the 12<sup>th</sup> position:

```js
textSelect(document.getElementById('theInput'), 12);
```

To select a portion of the input field:

```js
textSelect(document.getElementById('theInput'), 12, 15);
```

Answer (score 4):

It would be a huge [security?] issue if they allowed for something like this.
Imagine: you have a setInterval(function(){moveMouseToTopLeftCorner and alert garbage}, 1)...
The user would have his mouse moved to the top left.  And then alert would show up [which could be closed with enter].. upon which an alert would immediately pop up again.

You'd actually have to use your keyboard to open taskmanager and kill the browser >_>

However, it is probably possible with ActiveX [although thats IE only... and dumb]

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard of [Fake Cursor](https://github.com/Fighter178/FakeCursor/)?

This basically creates a fake cursor that you can manipulate with JavaScript. Very useful, but there are some limitations, like you cannot move the cursor outside of the screen, to for example, switch tabs. And all cursor events are prefixed with a v- to indicate that this event is virtual. The docs is in the README, if you're interested

**disclaimer**: I am the package author

Comment: It uses 'modern' features like ES6 syntax and the Pointer Lock API. This may be an issue for compatibility, but probably not, in most circumstances.