# Imitation of hover property

Tags: c#, jquery

I have a textbox and a button. I need to imitate the hover property for a textbox (if textbox value is empty) on button click.

I've tried the following, but it doesn't work:

**HTML**

```
<input id="surname" type="text" runat="server" />
<button id="Button1" runat="server" type="submit" onserverclick="RegistrationBtn_Click">OK</button>
```

**Script**

```
 function MakeHover() {
     $("#surname").mouseenter();
 }
```

**C#**

```
if (surname.Value == "")
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Hover", "MakeHover();", true);
```

Comment: I'm afraid this doesnt make a lot of sense.  You want to make the mouse hover over the text box when its not there?  Or is it that you want to dynamically add the `OnHover` event to your page?

Comment: @paqogomez yes, you are right. I want to make the mouse hover over the text box when its not there

Comment: Pretty sure that would be a big security problem.  Check out [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752501/move-the-mouse-pointer-to-a-specific-position) [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322603/move-mouse-pointer-in-javascript) answers.