# How to force the cursor into the input field if a button clicked?

Tags: javascript, html

What i want to illustrate, is what i want. The text transforms into an input field when the user clicks on it. But it will be the best if the cursor will be there on click. How to earn it?

```js
const input = () => {
  const field = document.querySelector('input');
  document.querySelector('p').style.display = 'none';
  field.style.display = 'block'
}
```

```css
input{
  display: none
}
```

```html
<p id='target' onClick='input()'>Click</p>
<input
  type='text' 
  value='type'
  name='name' 
/>
```

Comment: You can't move the user cursor. For your case I recommand to give the focus on your input. Add this to your function document.getElementById("yourinputID").focus();

Comment: You can focus the input, but you can't move the cursor

Comment: I suppose the OP means the caret, not the cursor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, [you can't move the cursor using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322603/move-mouse-pointer-in-javascript) but what you can do is focus the element using [`HTMLElement.focus()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus), so typing on the keyboard will result in input in the field:

```js
const input = () => {
  const field = document.querySelector('input');
  document.querySelector('p').style.display = 'none';
  field.style.display = 'block'
  field.focus() // focus the element
}
```

```css
input{
  display: none
}
```

```html
<p id='target' onClick='input()'>Click</p>
<input
  type='text' 
  value='type'
  name='name' 
/>
```

Comment: Be aware of browser support https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus

Comment: @executable Yes, it's not very well supported, but it's better than nothing

Answer (score 3):

> The [`HTMLElement.focus()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus) method sets focus on the specified element, if it can be focused.

```js
const input = () => {
  const field = document.querySelector('input');
  document.querySelector('p').style.display = 'none';
  field.style.display = 'block';
  field.focus();
}
```

```css
input{
  display: none
}
```

```html
<p id='target' onClick='input()'>Click</p>
<input
  type='text' 
  value='type'
  name='name' 
/>
```