# Javascript move mouse to specified location

Tags: javascript, browser, browser-automation

I can click a specified location wit that code

```
document.elementFromPoint(x, y).click();
```

but how can ı move the mouse with javascript,thanks! (The reason I do this is that I write an automation bot and when the mouse is hovered over a button, the text changes, only if I click it, the text does not change.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Move mouse pointer in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322603/move-mouse-pointer-in-javascript)